# Difference between using higher scope variables and using variables explicitly passed in a function

Tags: function, scope, global-variables

I mainly code in JS, but I guess this would apply to many languages.

What is the effective difference between a global/higher scope variable in a function versus using a variable passed into the function, and vice versa?

```
let somevariable = 5 ;

function somefuntion() {
  let scopedvariable = 10;
  return scopedvariable*myvariable
}

somefunction();

// OR

let myvariable = 5 ;

function somefuntion(somevariable ) {
  let scopedvariable = 10;
  return scopedvariable *somevariable
}
somefunction(myvariable);
```

Comment: If you change `somevariable` in your second example, eg: `somevariable++`, the global variable won't be impacted, whereas in the first example it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function uses a variable from scope that might cause a side effect(function modifying the outer variable) and this is considered bad practice because makes function [impure](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-a-pure-function-in-javascript-acb887375dfe/).

Global variables considered bad practice and should only be used if variable is constant. If the variable is constant it is okay, because now function can't modify the scope.